# How to use google.com on the new-tab page in Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, geolocation

I'm currently on a French IP address, and Chrome (on Windows) always uses Google France on the new-tab page, even if I went to google.com/ncr to disable the IP-based redirect.

[image: google.fr]

This is pretty annoying since whenever there's a nice Doodle its tooltip is in French and clicking it uses a French search term.

Is there a setting to force chrome to use google.com for that page?

Answer (score 0):

The "google.com" finds out which country you are in using the URL. For example when I was using a Japanese VPN my Google redirected to "google.co.jp". However without a VPN (in the UK) it would redirect me to google.co.uk.

---

So in your case in the Google Chrome preferences set the new tab to open up "google.co.uk" instead of .com.

Comment: I'm not talking about a custom homepage. I'd like to keep the normal "new tab" page of chrome.

Answer (score 0):

http://google.com
-> "Settings" in the lower right hand corner of the window/tab
-> [pop-up-Menu] Search Settings
-> Languages
-> (*) English

Comment: Are you sure that this affects the **new tab page of chrome**?

Comment: That is a persistent setting. I'm using Swedish locale, but run all software in English. *The translations are too oriented towards non-tech-savvy persons.*